# После обновления до Ubuntu 18 перестал работать левый ALT в приложениях

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

Что делать?

Комбинации самой системы (ALT + F4, например) работают, но как только в приложении вводишь комбинацию начинающуюся с левого альта, она не воспринимается как комбинация в принципе.

В меню раскладки клавиатуры при нажатии на альт клавиша не загорается как рабочая.

Comment: возможно потому, что у Вас переключалка клавиатуры по alt-shift

Comment: В Убунту 18 невозможно поставить стандартными способами  переключалку клавиатуры по alt-shift. Зато можно с помощью Gnome tweaker; дёргал туда сюда - никаких изменений.

Comment: я бы сам заминусовал свой коммент за фанатичность, но серьёзно, сколько линуксовых ДЕ я не пробовал, во всех обязательно всплывает набор глюков, которые даже не гуглятся. только xfce можно использовать повседневно, больше ничего! у меня в десятках дистрибутивов всегда были подобные проблемы и решение у всех одно - ставь xubuntu и не мучайся!

Comment: советую поставить переключалку на капслок (при этом обычная функция капс-лока будет работать с зажатым шифтом). очень удобно, поскольку эта здоровенная кнопка обычно не используется :)

Comment: да, сам так делаю, даже под виндой стоит recaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогла комбинация:
Настройки-> Устройства-> Клавиатура -> Сбросить всё..